# Webview no muestra contenido en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, android-studio, html5, webview-android

Buen día, Quisiera pedir un poco de ayuda con respecto a un problema que tengo en una app en el cual implemente un `WebView` y en algunos dispositivos carga perfectamente la web app y en otros no, esto se presenta más que todo tratar de mostrar unas imágenes, como menciono, solo es en algunos dispositivos en los que no muestra las imágenes y en otros si las muestra.

he implementado este código para el `WebView`

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebDemo);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://demoapp.com");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Aclaro que en los navegadores móviles si se muestran las imágenes, en algunos casos se muestran en Chrome Android, en otros casos no, pero si en otros navegadores, pero en la app no.

Comment: Un poco extraño el comportamiento que comentas, se muestra que no cargo las imágenes o simplemente no se muestran, podrías agregar una imagen de que es lo que sucede?

Comment: Cuando empecé con Android mi primera opción fue usar WebView, en parte porque me pareció lo más fácil. Pero a la larga desistí de su uso, porque me trajo muchos problemas y porque se hacía difícil mostrar el contenido como lo quería. Opté entonces por crear un WebService que me trae la información en un JSON, el cual leo y muestro su contenido. Entre ese contenido hay código HTML y se muestra perfectamente en un `TextView`. Si es tu propio dominio, recomendaría que desistas de WebView pasando a crear tu propio WebService en formato JSON. Es mejor y es más ligero.

Comment: No se ven las imágenes, pero como comente inicialmente, solo en algunos dispositivos. He realizado un test en 6 dispositivos diferentes, donde en 4 se muestran las imágenes, y en dos de ellos no se muestran, no las carga, no queda ni el espacio en blanco, solo muestra el header y el footer de la web app.